# How to use Google authentication without redirection?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-authentication

Is there a way to use Google accounts to authenticate my own personal website? I understand Google provides an API for authentication but it requires redirection. Is there anyway to have a customized login process without being redirected to Google?

By the way I'm a total noob when it comes to user authentication. I did try to find a preexisting thread but was unable to find one.

Comment: The redirection is there to prevent [man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks.  It is a necessary part of Federated OpenID Login.

Comment: That sounds like Google. But just for clarification, the process defined here (http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html#ClientLogin) requires redirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For exactly the reason given by Kris, Google (along with similar [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth) providers) doesn't allow you to authenticate users directly.
It's a security measure to protect both themselves and their users from the Web equivalent of ATM card skimmers.

Comment: I find that... incredibly surprising. I guess I was wrong. The advice on why you might want to avoid it holds, but thanks for pointing out the discrepancy :)

Comment: ClientLogin API is primarily targeted at mobile and desktop apps, which can not easily use web-based OpenID or OAuth. Otherwise Google recommends to use OpenID and OAuth where possible.

Comment: For reasons that you stated (MIM attack) I'd never type my google password in 3rd party web site.

Comment: @Peter It's not even a MitM attack when the attacker identifies themselves as a different person.

Answer (score 3):

I have a usability answer rather than a technical one.

I am unsure if this is doable but, even if it is doable, I would highly suggest NOT doing it. Think of it this way: you want a user to use their Google account to login to your website. If you were that user, would you feel more comfortable entering your login information on a Google website or someone else's website that has nothing to do with Google?

Comment: Thanks definitely makes sense.